# Pizza Topping combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I run a pizza joint in Seattle, USA, and would love to know how many different combinations of pie we can create.

We have:

- 23 toppings
- 12 "house" pizzas
- 2 sizes (medium and large)
- two different bases (tomato sauce and olive oil)
- the ability to do half and half pizzas

Constraints and rules:

- maximum of four toppings per pizza or per side
- house pizzas count as distinct choices
- no substitutions or exclusions on house pizzas

Comment: By "house pizzas" do you mean fixed, non-alterable ones?

Comment: You would owe a lot more than a slice. If you want mathematical help for your business, do the right thing, and hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: "Choose from over 100 million different pizzas!" me thinks "over 23 toppings" is more efficient :)

Comment: Can I get in on a slice too

Comment: You seem to have gotten your answer. May I suggest that you send a donation of, say, 1,000 dollars to the Mathematical Association of America, so that, 30 years from now, when your children inherit your pizza empire, there will be someone around to do their mathematics for them.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully your aim is to learn something from this exercise, rather than to simply stick the final number on a flyer. I am providing the following answer under this assumption of good will.

Let us first calculate the number of possible whole (i.e. not half-half) pizzas that you can do. Assuming that a pizza with zero toppings (i.e. a margherita) is valid, we have:

$$N = 2\cdot2\cdot\sum_{n_t=0}^{4} \binom{23}{n_t},$$

where $n_t$ denotes the number of toppings, and the two $2$'s account for the two possible sizes and the two possible bases.

Now for the number of half-half pizzas. We can consider a half-half pizza as a combination of two, non-identical pizzas from the above $N$. However, there is an important detail that we need to take care of: we cannot combine a medium pizza with a large pizza. Therefore, we split $N$ in half to get the number of possible medium *or* large pizzas. Then, $\frac{1}{2}\frac{N}{2}(\frac{N}{2}-1)$ gives us the number of possible half-half medium *or* large pizzas. The number of possible medium *and* large half-half pizzas is thus $\frac{N}{2}(\frac{N}{2}-1)$.

Now the total number of possible pizzas is given by: $$T=12+N+\frac{N}{2}(\frac{N}{2}-1).$$

$T$ turns out to be 475,523,454, i.e. you can do a total of almost half a billion different pizzas.

Assuming that your ovens can cook, say, up to 10 pizzas at a time, and that a pizza takes around 10 minutes to cook, it would take you around 904 *years non-stop* to make every possible pizza. Good luck with that :-).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this would just be a product of factorials.

(23!) * (12!) * (2!) * (2!) * (2!) = 9.9065259 * 10^31

That's assuming you don't double up on anything.

EDIT: After reading MGA's answer, I'm pretty sure he's right. I assumed that the 12 would be part of the combination which it shouldn't be. Also, I didn't account for the half pizza reducing the possible combinations of toppings.